# Minimizing a function with some restrictions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need help in finding a way to minimize a function with some complex constraints.
I'm not an expert in this field, but I'm still trying to understand if I can do something with my problem.

So, here's the functions:

\begin{equation}
\min z = \{ds_1*[(cp_{11}*qp_1*pp_{11}+...+(cp_{n1}*qp_n*pp_{n1})]+...+ds_m*[(cp_{1m}*qp_1*pp_{1m}+...+(cp_{nm}*qp_n*pp_{nm})]\}
\end{equation}

with those given **constants**

\begin{equation}
ds_x > 0, qp_x > 0, pp_{xy} > 0
\end{equation}

and

$$
cp_{yx} = 
\begin{cases}
1 \\
0 
\end{cases},
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^m cp_{iy} = 1 \text{ (only one element can be 1 in the whole column)}
\end{equation}
$$

what I have to do is to find the values for those `cp` terms to minimize the function.

Now, I know a little bit of optimization (simplex, branch & bound and stuff like this) but I've never went that deep and this one looks really complex to me.

Being a computer scientist, I thought of making some kind of backtracking stuff, but even with a small instance (let's say `n=3` and `m=7`) I'd have to work on

\begin{equation}
2^{3*7}=2097152
\end{equation}

different combinations, which is really a lot.

Do you have any suggestion on this?

EDIT:
Based on @DumpsterDoofus's answer, this is what I tried (with some real values)

\begin{equation}
d=[7, 5, 11], \text{vector with the } ds_j \text{ constants}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
p=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 1\\2 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 7 & 2 & 3\\3 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
, \text{matrix with the } pp_{ij} \text{ constants}
\end{equation}

assuming that

\begin{equation}
qp_i = 1, \forall i
\end{equation}

we have

\begin{equation}
k=
\begin{bmatrix}
7*5 & 7*2 & 7*5 & 7*3 & 7*7 & 7*1 & 7*1\\5*2 & 5*8 & 5*3 & 5*2 & 5*7 & 5*2 & 5*3\\11*3 & 11*6 & 11*4 & 11*5 & 11*9 & 11*1 & 11*1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
35 & 14 & 35 & 21 & 49 & 7 & 7\\10 & 40 & 15 & 10 & 35 & 10 & 15\\33 & 66 & 44 & 55 & 99 & 11 & 11
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which, translated to a vecotr, becomes

\begin{equation}
k=[35,10,33,14,40,66,35,15,44,21,10,55,49,35,99,7,10,11,7,15,11]
\end{equation}

(I did it manually and now I corrected it after proper explanation of the `vec()` function)

Now that I've got the value of `k`, I'm ready to run this in *Mathematica*:

```
n=3;
m=7;
j[k_]:=ConstantArray[1,k];
k={35,10,33,14,40,66,35,15,44,21,10,55,49,35,99,7,10,11,7,15,11};
A=ArrayFlatten[{IdentityMatrix[m]\[TensorProduct]j[n]}];
b=j[m]\[TensorProduct]{1,0};
Round@LinearProgramming[k,A,b]
```

> Output: {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0} [Edited after changing k to its correct value]

Changing the output back to a matrix leads to this:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

which <s>is clearly wrong as we have one column full of zeroes and another one full of ones.</s> seems correct now.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a step-by-step answer, but one question: you say $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m cp_{yi} = 1 \text{ (only one element can be 1 in the whole column)}$, but a sum over the second index is actually doing the sum horizontally (ie, summing over each row), so shouldn't it actually be that "only one element can be 1 in the whole *row*", instead of *column*?

Comment: In my answer, I assume that your *formula* has a typo, and that you really meant to write $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m cp_{iy} = 1$, ie, that only one element can be 1 in the whole column. If this is incorrect, I can modify my answer to work for rows instead.

Comment: The reason you're getting an incorrect answer is because you're vectorizing is incorrect; vectorization is done by stacking the columns of a matrix, and vice versa for the reverse operation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics). I'll edit my answer to include a `vec` function, and run it on the values you provided.

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused. You say that $m=7$, but then you have $d=[7,5,11]$ with length 3, but that contradicts the formula for $z$ you provided, which states that the $ds_i$ values range in $i$ from $1$ to $m$. So shouldn't $d$ be of length $7$, and $qp$ be of length 3, based on the formula you provided? Or is that a typo in your formula, and the $m$'s and $n$'s should be swapped?

Comment: I guess you've spotted another typo then, sorry for that but I'm not really used in writing this kind of things. After correcting the vectorization and doing the inverse on the given output I've got a matrix that seems correct. I'll update the question again, let me know if I did it right this time :)

Comment: I updated my answer, and I got the same result as you did. Might want to plug in a couple other permutations and check if it's actually optimal, but it's probably correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that since $ds_x,qp_x,pp_{xy}$ are constants, the expression $z$ can be simplified greatly:
$$z=\{ds_1[(cp_{11}qp_1pp_{11}+...+(cp_{m1}qp_mpp_{m1})]+...+ds_n[(cp_{1n}qp_1pp_{1n}+...+(cp_{mn}qp_mpp_{mn})]\}
\\
=\sum_{i,j}k_{ij}cp_{ij}
\\
=\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{c}$$
where 
$$\mathbf{c}=\text{vec}(cp)
\\
\mathbf{k}=\text{vec}(k)$$
where $\text{vec}()$ is the matrix-to-vector operator, and
$$k_{ij}=ds_iqp_jpp_{ij}.$$

Let $cp$ be an $n\times m$ matrix (as you describe in your question). The constraint equation (sum over **columns** of $cp$ is always 1) can be written as
$$A\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{j}_m$$
where $\mathbf{j}_m$ is a list of $m$ ones, and
$$A=\text{ArrayFlatten}[\{I_m\otimes\mathbf{j}_n\}]$$
where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix and $\otimes$ is the tensor product.$^1$

At that point, you're basically done, since you can then invoke `LinearProgramming`$^2$. Here's a very concise example (for $n=5,m=2$) which randomly generates coefficients $k_{ij}$ and then optimizes the resulting system:

```
n = 5;
m = 2;
j[k_] := ConstantArray[1, k];
k = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n m];
A = ArrayFlatten[{IdentityMatrix[m]\[TensorProduct]j[n]}];
b = j[m]\[TensorProduct]{1, 0};
Round@LinearProgramming[k, A, b]
```

> Output: {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}

The only confusing point is the definition $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{j}_m\otimes\{1,0\}$, which is done because we want Mathematica to use the constraint $A\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{j}_m$, rather than the default syntax `LinearProgramming[k, A, j[m]]`, which would use $A\mathbf{c}\geq\mathbf{j}_m$.$^3$

To get the answer for your particular problem, simply replace the line `k = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n m]` with your actual values for the problem you're trying to solve!

### Minor notes:

$^1$: As an example, for the case $cp$ is $5\times 2$, you have
$$A\mathbf{c}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 cp_{11} \\
 cp_{12} \\
 cp_{13} \\
 cp_{14} \\
 cp_{15} \\
 cp_{21} \\
 cp_{22} \\
 cp_{23} \\
 cp_{24} \\
 cp_{25} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\mathbf{j}_2.$$

As you can see, this ensures that the sum over each column of $cp$ is 1.

$^2$: The advantage of `LinearProgramming` (rather than `Minimize`) is that it's pretty well-suited to tackling very large problems, with a large number of variables and constraints, whereas `Minimize` doesn't scale well with problem size.

$^3$: From the documentation page from `LinearProgramming`:

[image]

By setting the $s_i=0$ you enforce constraint equality; a sneaky way to do this syntax is to use $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{j}_m\otimes\{1,0\}$ instead of $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{j}_m$.

### Edit:

Based on the corrections you provided, here's the result for your specific numbers:

```
n = 3;
m = 7;
vec[m_] := Flatten[m\[Transpose]];
mat[v_] := Partition[v, n]\[Transpose];
j[k_] := ConstantArray[1, k];
d = {7, 5, 11};
p = ( {
    {5, 2, 5, 3, 7, 1, 1},
    {2, 8, 3, 2, 7, 2, 3},
    {3, 6, 4, 5, 9, 1, 1}
   } );
q = j[m];
k = vec[p (d\[TensorProduct]q)];
A = ArrayFlatten[{IdentityMatrix[m]\[TensorProduct]j[n]}];
b = j[m]\[TensorProduct]{1, 0};
mat[LinearProgramming[k, A, b]] // MatrixForm
```

> Output: $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: I've upvoted your answer until I have the chance to actually try it, but it seems what I was looking for

Comment: I just edited the question with my work based on your solution because the result is not what I expected and I think I did something wrong

Comment: The edit was perfect, thanks for the reply and sorry for messing up things :)